# Is there a way to get VirtualBox to work with an Intel 64 bit processor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtual-machine

I am creating a VMWare VM from my old laptop.  Since VMWare Player is not free for me to use at work, I am looking at converting the resulting VM to a VirtualBox VM.  (There are several tutorials on how to do this.)

But as I was going to install VirtualBox I saw that it [only supports x86/AMD64](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

[image: Virtual Box Supported OSes]

Both my laptop and my new computer have an Intel 64 bit processor.

It is a bit confusing because the [main page](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for VirtualBox says it supports AMD64/Intel64.  But the download omits Intel64.

Am I out of luck?  Or is there some way to make it work?  (Or will it just work even though it says it is only for amd64?)

Comment: This is a VMWare article, but you might find it useful. Some computers require that virtualization technology be enabled in the host bios. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003944

It's completely unrelated to your question, but still might be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**AMD64** is the [x86_64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) standard.

AMD licensed their [64-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Intel_64) *x86* implementation to Intel after Intel's non-backwards-compatible *IA64* implementation was a [market failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium#Market_share).

All **Core 2 Duo** and newer (all the *i3*, *i5*, *i7*) (exception: early *Atom*) Intel CPUs support AMD's AMD64 x86_64 implementation.

So just choose **x86/amd64** (provided you are running a 64-bit OS)

Note: Often software referring as compatible with *x86* is in reference to x86 32-bit. x86_64 CPUs can run either 32-bit or 64-bit OSes.

Comment: Be carefull with Core2Duo: Not ALL Core2Duo's support x64. Especially in the mobile/laptop versions there are some models which are 32-bit only.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, however they are easily confused with the **Core Duo** (Core 1 generation) which are 32-bit CPUs.

Comment: I did a bit of research and I must admit being wrong. I'm confusing them with the Pentium Mobile series. These come in x64 (Core2Duo based) and x32-only (CoreDuo based) versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the download more closely, you see that it supports both x86 and AMD64. As a result, you can use the default download without a problem. I can confirm this because VirtualBox is working on my AMD64 computer.